# Customer Registration Form Template Not Working On Site Home Page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to call Magento customer registration form on my home page. When I call it on the home page I try both ways, static block or template.phtml file and my site stops working. Can anyone suggest a solution to me?

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('register-form')->toHtml();
```

---

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('persistent/customer/form/mini.register')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

when using a template file, add the '.phtml' extension to the name of the file.

in your example:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('persistent/customer/form/mini.register.phtml')->toHtml();
```

please not that the code above will only work in template files.
if you are trying to add this to your homepage through the admin cms page, then you would do this:

```
{{ block type="core/template" template="persistent/customer/form/mini.register.phtml" }}
```

or through a layout file:

```
<block type="core/template" template="persistent/customer/form/mini.register.phtml" />
```